# How to get this kind of query in NHibernate : SELECT DISTINCT FileName From CustomerFile WHERE name = ' ' AND timeframe = ''

Tags: hql, icriteria

Please do not redirect me towards the other similar kinds of HQL in Stackoverflow, because they did not work for me. I really appreciate your direction on it. Thanks.

Reproducing this kind of query in Nhibernate with ICriteria API :

```
 SELECT DISTINCT FileName From CustomerFile WHERE name = ' ' AND timeframe = ''
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the custom SQL that you've sketched in, above, and map the result column to Strings? Why jump through ORM hoops to do something simple?

```
session
 .CreateSQLQuery("SELECT DISTINCT FileName From CustomerFile WHERE name = ' ' AND timeframe = ''")
 .AddScalar("FILENAME", NHibernateUtil.String)
```

Comment: Thanks, project's entire Dat aaccess logic is done with NHibernate, so I dont want to deviate it from it. Of course doing this with SQL server is really trivial task.

Comment: To get compile time integrity perhaps?

Comment: It *is* still "done with NHibernate"! See https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html_single/#d0e8963

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for the hyperlink.